# Using variable as shorthand for Foo.prototype

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, prototype

I just started using module pattern in JavaScript to declare functional objects, but found it annoying to repeat the Foo.prototype keyword in declaring all those public functions you might need.

So I came up with using some shorthand variable for convenience as follows.

```
(function(){    
   var Foo = function(){
      alert('created Foo');
   }

   // shorthand for further creation of public functions
   var pro = Foo.prototype;

   //public function with shorthand
   pro.bar = function(){
      //some cool stuff here
   }
   return window.Foo = Foo;
}());
```

Question is: is there some reason to prevent me from saving these few characters regarding functionality or some unexpected error or is this safe to do?
This seems to work just fine for the cases I used it in?

Comment: That's fine but don't forget to `var` your variable `Foo`

Comment: @Xotic750: Then there wouldn't be reason to run that code at all, because `Foo` wouldn't be accessible outside. I believe `Foo` is intended to be global, but a better way to do this is `var Foo = ...; window.Foo = Foo;`. *edit:* Or maybe not, who knows :D

Comment: Felix is right! Not visible anymore. I guess I need to return the window.foo as updated

Comment: @Felix: yep, who knows but my guess as it was in a closure, is that would be the intent. Or maybe being return to another external local. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, prototypes is an object like any other when it comes to modifying it. Keeping a reference to it is absolutely ok

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

It's OK to do so, but is sometimes confusing for that if you have code like this:

```
var pro='123';

(function () {
    var Foo=function () {
        alert('created Foo');
    };

    // shorthand for further creation of public functions
    var pro=Foo.prototype;

    var x=new Foo();
    alert(pro);
})();

alert(pro);
```

or accidentally write it like this:

```
var pro='123';

(function () {
    var Foo=function () {
        alert('created Foo');
    };

    // use pro without var
    pro=Foo.prototype;

    var x=new Foo();
    alert(pro);
})();

alert(pro);
```

The former will work properly, just it's confusing when reading the code, the reader need to be aware of that the `var pro` in the IIFE is not the same `pro` in the global scope.

The latter may be a terrible error that the `pro` is reassigned and lost its original value.

So I proposed the code as it's in my original answer because you cannot modify `this` inside the function.

---

I think you can do it in this way ..

```
var Foo=(function () {
    function Foo() {
        alert('created Foo');
    }

    // inside the anonymous function `this` is `Foo.prototype`
    (function () {
        this.bar=function () {
            //some cool stuff here
        };
    }).call(Foo.prototype);

    return Foo;
})();

var x=new Foo();
x.bar();
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't answer the OP's question ;)

Comment: Thanks! Still this is another piece helping me to understand that whole thing!

Comment: @FelixKling: Hmm .. is it better now .. ?